# Consumer Class in Java not getting messages from the registered topic. Kafka with Spring Boot App

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using Kafka with Spring Boot. I use Rest Controllers to call Producer/Consumer API's. Producer Class is able to add messages to the topic. I verified using command line utility (Console-consumer.sh). However my Consumer class is not able to receive them in Java for further processing.
**@KafkaListener** used in Consumer class listener method should be able to receive messages when my Producer class posts messages to the topic which is not happening. Any help appreciated.

Is it still necessary for consumer to subscribe and poll for records when I have already created KafkaListenerContainerFactory that is responsible for invoking Consumer Listener method when a message is posted to the topic?

**Consumer Config Class**

> KafkaPayload is a POJO class

```java
@Configuration
class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    private String bootstrapServers = "localhost:9092";

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, KafkaPayload> consumerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
                bootstrapServers);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props) ;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, KafkaPayload>> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, KafkaPayload> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerConfigs());
        return factory;
    }
```

**Consumer Class**

```java
@Component
public class KafkaListenersExample {

    private final List<KafkaPayload> messages = new ArrayList<>();

    @KafkaListener(topics = "test_topic")
    public void listener(KafkaPayload data) {
        synchronized (messages){
            messages.add(data);
        }
    }

    public List<KafkaPayload> getMessages(){
        return messages;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Messages produced before first consumer connected lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64558833/messages-produced-before-first-consumer-connected-lost)

Comment: Right - add `props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");` if you want a new consumer to consume existing records in the topic.